# How to make a user upload folder and display specific content in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I am trying to create an upload folder for each user on my site, and display their photos in a specific area. I have been able to get the codeigniter upload helper to work and can upload files to a folder. Now I want to be able to:

1. have the photos upload by a specific user be placed in a folder for that user created on the fly specific to their id
2. auto size the photo for two sizes. A thumbnail and a larger size

I think I have it set up from research on how to do those things I just don't know how to plug in their id's syntactically as well as creating a folder and uploading it.

the last step would be displaying these photos in the locations of my choice tied to their ids.

Here is my controller

```
public function upload()
    {
        mkdir('./upload/' . $this->session->userdata('id'), 0777);
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = 'PATH TO FOLDER??';
        $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['width']     = 75;
        $config['height']   = 50;

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 

        $this->image_lib->resize();
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $data['main_content'] = 'account/upload';
            $this->load->view('includes/templates/main_page_template', $data);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating the users directory but not setting it as the upload path...

```
$user_folder = './upload/' . $this->session->userdata('id');
if(!is_dir($user_folder)){
    mkdir($user_folder, 0777);
}
...
$config['upload_path'] = $user_folder;
....
```

Comment: That is working, however I am still getting an error: "Severity Warning: mkdir()[functon.mkdir]: File exists

Comment: Check if the directory exists before trying to create it.. I will update the answer.